# On the Decomposition of Simple Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In the proof of Lemma 1.4.20 in *Classical Fourier Analysis, 3rd Edition* (Loukas Grafakos as the author), it seems that the following fact is tacitly used which I cannot figure out how it works:

If $f$ is of the form
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=m}^{n}2^{-i}\chi_{A_{i}},
\end{align*}
where $m<n$ are integers, then $f$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{l}a_{j}\chi_{E_{j}},
\end{align*}
where $a_{j}\geq 0$ and $E_{1}\subseteq E_{2}\subseteq\cdots\subseteq E_{n}$.

How to see this? Even that I put
\begin{align*}
f=2^{-1}\chi_{A_{1}}+2^{-2}\chi_{A_{2}}+2^{-3}\chi_{A_{3}},
\end{align*}
it is hard to find such increasing $E_{i}$. I started by letting $E_{1}=A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap A_{3}$, but then what is the proper form of $E_{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, any $f$ which takes only finitely many values, all non-negative, can be written in such a form. Suppose that the values $f$ takes are (in descending order) $v_1, v_2, v_3, \ldots, v_n$. Then we define the sets $E_1 = f^{-1}(\{v_1\})$, $E_2 = f^{-1}(\{v_1, v_2\})$, and so on. The values of the coefficients $a_j$ is given by $a_j = v_j - v_{j+1}$ for $j < n$ and $a_n = v_n$.

Now take any $x$, and say that $f(x) = v_j$. Then $x$ lies in $E_j, E_{j+1}, \ldots, E_n$, so
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \chi_{E_i}(x) = \sum_{i=j}^n a_i = (v_j - v_{j+1}) + (v_{j+1} - v_{j+2}) + \cdots + v_n = v_j.
$$

Comment: Hmm... this is straight to the point. I wonder if this is a standard exercise in any real analysis book. Anyway, thanks a lot.